# Where does Facebook cache video?

Tags: facebook

Few days ago, I played a video in Facebook app. Today, I tapped the same video just to know that the video was cached locally.

From where can I get this cache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find your cached videos under `/data/data/com.facebook.katana/files/video-cache`.

**Note:** To open that path, you need a rooted phone and a  root explorer app.